# Is it possible to connect VB.NET to GCM(Google Cloud Messaging)?

Tags: android, vb.net, google-cloud-messaging

I want to create a VB.net application which will trigger to sent notification in my Android Application? Does anyone know on how i will implement GCM in VB.net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the

> Google Cloud Messaging Client & Server Libraries ported to C#

https://github.com/Redth/GCMSharp

Comment: how about using vb.net?